# Density in a weighted, directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, network-programming, igraph

sorry to post back to back but I was just looking at the density function of igraph and it does not seem to consider weights in a graph (correct me if I am wrong). I looked into the literature and only found this

"The sum of the weights of the edges in the graph, divided by the number of possible edges i.e. |V| x (|V|-1)"

In my case I have a 188x188 one-mode network, which is directed, asymmetric weighted. The total edge weight is 2112, number of edges is 468.

From igraph I get ~0,013 and from this solution I get ~0,06

My question is now if you think this a valid approach or if anyone has heard of a different solution to this problem.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? "Density" is just a definition, what are you trying to achieve?
Also - My guess is that igraph (what ever that is) is calculating density for an undirected graph hence the result.

Comment: If you divide by `|V|(|V|-1)/2` you get `0.12`. Usually you divide by 2 so as not to count the same edge twice for undirected graphs.

Comment: Well the question is if density makes sense for weighted, directed graphs. It is usually a descriptive measure to show how connected a graph is in general and that is what I want to show. Igraph does 468/(188+(188-1)=0,013, which is for unweighted, directed networks. I did 2112/(188+(188-1)=0,06 to consider the weights as well.

Comment: Density is not very well defined for weighted graphs. Positive weights are sometimes OK, but just think about a graph with both positive and negative weights. Then your density might be close to zero, even if the graph is full of (strongly weighted) edges! So igraph just ignores the weights.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very old, but I just noticed that there's an error in the formula that you are giving above.

You actually need to **multiply** l by 2, not divide by 2 in an undirected graph.

In an undirected graph, you have to double the number of lines in a graph because they are undirected.

[image: Density for undirected graph]

[image: Density in directed graph]

OP: when you say "In my case I have a 188x188 one-mode network, which is directed, asymmetric weighted. The total edge weight is 2112, number of edges is 468."

This is L/n*(n-1) = 2112 / 35156 = 0.06

However, if igraph is not factoring in the weights, the answer would be:

L/n*(n-1) = 468 / 35156 = 0.013, which is consistent with what you reported earlier. I hope this has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The function edge_density of irgraph does not consider weights.
If you call it on a weighted graph, it treats the graph as unweighted and returns the density: `nb_edges / V*(V-1)` for directed graphs, and `nb_edges / V*(V-1) / 2` for undirected grapsh.

This is not stated in the documentation of igraph, as far as I know.

Yet, I am not sure whether density makes sense for weighted networks in general, so I do not see the merit of the definition you refer to.

Something similar might be useful for more specific applications, but here one should probably program ones own function.